# Method in SSRS Custom Assembly Fails After Pushing to Server

Tags: c#, reporting-services

**Background** - I have developed a custom assembly for my SSRS server that I use to dynamically generate default values for particular report parameters.  Some of these functions require a call to my database, mostly funneled through a generic function named ExecuteScalar().  I am using cascading parameters to pass particular criteria to these methods.

**Issue** - Calling these methods returns the correct result when ran on my local machine. However, it stops working once I deploy it to my server.  The DLL is in the right place and IS being found.  I know this because I can set my method to pass back a hard-coded value just fine.  The issue comes when I try to open my connection. Once this happens SSRS spits out the oh-so-specific error *Error during processing of ‘Start’ report parameter. (rsReportParameterProcessingError)* (Start is the name of the parameter for which I am querying the default value).  I have tried implementing the suggestions at this site to no avail http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2007/01/22/Reporting_Services__Your_Custom_Assembly__Error._WTF.aspx. (Setting the Permission State did not fix it and setting the assembly to AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers wouldn't even compile)

I am using SSRS 2005 and a C# assembly.  Any help you can provide would be awesome & appreciated!

```
public T ExecuteScalar<T>(String query)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            this.GenerateConnectionString("Test"); //Creates global var conn string
            cmd = GetSqlCommand(query); //Creates cmd object using global conn string

           //If I return a hard-coded date here, I have no problems.
            cmd.Connection.Open();
           //If I return a hard-coded date here, I get the error msg stated above.

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), typeof(T));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error in " + (new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame()).GetMethod().Name + "()", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cmd != null)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```